# Request Tracking Authorization for iOS Application Facebook App Events

Tags: swift, facebook, facebook-sdk-4.0, apptrackingtransparency, in-app-events

I am trying to integrate app events for my iOS application. Below are the steps I have taken:

- Configured Facebook App and added iOS platform
- Linked ad account
- Set up dev environment and SDK
- Configured my project plist
- Connected app delegate
- Added manual logs

No log was getting recorded. After some research I found out that in iOS 14+ `isAutoLogAppEventsEnabled`, `isAdvertiserTrackingEnabled` and `isAdvertiserIDCollectionEnabled` have to be enabled.It is also done.

Any help is really appreciated on this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Facebook [documentation](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/app-events/getting-started-app-events-ios) on app events is very vague. It does not contain any information about `ATTrackingManager` which is necessary to track events. Below are the steps I have taken to successfully connect app events (iOS 15):

1. All steps in the [documentation](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/app-events/getting-started-app-events-ios).
2. Info.plist

   [image]
3. `SceneDelegate`:

   [image]

   ```
   func sceneDidBecomeActive(_ scene: UIScene) {
            print("sceneDidBecomeActive")

            DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + 1) {[weak self] in
                        self?.requestTracking()
            }     
      }
   ```

[image]

This will bring up the following tracking pop up at app launch:

[image]

4. In your viewcontroller:

[image]